# What does infinite-scroll-immediate-check do in ngInfiniteScroll?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

The documentation:

> `infinite-scroll-immediate-chec` (optional) - {`boolean`} - A boolean expression that indicates that the directive should check immediately to see if a scroll event would trigger an evaluation of the infinite scroll expression even if a scroll event does not occur. Useful if it's possible that the content inside the directive's element is not tall enough to fill up the entire browser window's height. Defaults to `true`.

This seems like a difficult way of saying that it will fill the page with results on the first load if the initial amount of results isn't enough to fill the page. So if I show 3 results on first load, but they don't reach the bottom of the page/element, then it will call the `loadMore()` event until it does.

But this doesn't seem to happen. Just want to make sure I am reading this right since the description is a but grandiloquent.

Comment: It looks like you are right https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/blob/master/src/infinite-scroll.coffee#L190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per `ngInfiniteScroll`'s test case of [infinite-scroll-immediate-chec](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/blob/master/test/spec/ng-infinite-scroll.spec.coffee#L115), If this parameter is set as `true` (the default value), meanwhile the directive's element can not fill up the browser window' height, it will trigger a `loadMore()` immediately even you don't scroll your window at all. And this action will only be triggered once, therefor if there are 3 three tiny results on first load and they don't reach the bottom, function `loadMore()` won't be triggered until you scroll the window.

While if this parameter is set as false, you have to trigger the first call of `loadMore` manually or programmably.

Comment: Short but sweet explanation. Gre8 :)